# How do we see and/or detect neurons?

Tags: neuroscience, brain

I'm curious as to how we "see" neurons, for lack of a better term. Is it the detection of the neuro-transmitters? Can we literally see the electricity firing and moving throughout the pathways? Is it a combination of both, or something completely different, like scanners?

What kind of technology is used to do these things?

thank you!

Comment: Google is a good technology to find answers to these questions. Did you try it? Please try doing some looking up from your side before posting a question. Questions with no effort from the asker are usually not very useful to anyone (unless the question itself is quite good). Plus, your question is broad. If you are interested in these topics then you can check out the first few chapters of Principles of Neural Science by Eric Kandel et al.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the big thing in Neuroscience is imaging *in vivo* Calcium release which correlates with neuron action potentials, [seen here](https://youtu.be/p1eKi0PrqMI). Each white speck is a neuron, the black lines and circles are blood vessels. Using this method you can visualize distribution and activity of neurons in real time.